# Question on convergence of series, unable to understand it properly

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

> Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence and suppose the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is convergent with limit $\lambda$. Let $(b_n)$ be a new sequence whose terms are defined by $b_n = a_{n+1}$. Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ is convergent and find its limit.

We haven't covered convergence of series yet, but I was given this question to answer, and I'm thoroughly confused about how to even go about answering it. Any pointers or guidance in the right direction?

Comment: Cheers for the edit, i couldnt get it to embed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guide:

For all $\epsilon > 0, \exists M>0, m > M \implies \left|\sum_{n=1}^m a_n - \lambda\right|<\epsilon$.

Try to convert the statement above from $a_n$ to $b_n$.

Comment: I can do that, but how do I prove what b converges to, as I thought that any series that converges = 0

Comment: Nevermind, I've figured it out, I was being really stupid, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a(n)=a_{1}+a_{2}+a_{3}...=\lambda$...given

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b(n)=b_{1}+b_{2}+b_{3}+...=a_{2}+a_{3}+a_{4}+....=\lambda-a_{1}$  as $( b_{n}=a_{n+1})$